# Clearing the array before generating the same

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am facing a problem in clearing an array before reconstructing it. This is the code I have written

this is the code when a button with saveBtn as id is clicked

```
jQuery("#saveBtn").on('click',function(){
    var selectedColsArray =[];
    jQuery('#editDisplay li:not(.strike)').each(function(i){
        selCols = jQuery(this).text();
        selectedColsArray.push(selCols);
    });
    var divID = jQuery(this).parents().eq(2).attr('id');
    hideCols(selectedColsArray);
    jQuery('#editWindow').hide();
});

function hideCols(selectedCols){
    availableColsArr = [];
    jQuery('#documentReferences .dataTables_scrollHeadInner th').each(function(){
        columnName = jQuery(this).text();
        availableColsArr.push(columnName);
    });
    var result = [];
    var i = 0;
    jQuery.grep(availableColsArr, function(j) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(j, selectedCols) == -1) result.push(j);
        i++;
    });

    jQuery('#documentReferences .dataTables_scrollHeadInner th').each(function(){
        for(var k=0;k<result.length;k++){
            colText = jQuery(this).text();
            if(colText == result[k]){
                var colID = jQuery(this).attr('class').split(/\b/)[0];
                jQuery('.'+colID).hide();
            }
        }

        for(var k=0;k<selectedCols.length;k++){
            colText1 = jQuery(this).text();
            if(colText1 == selectedCols[k]){
                var colID = jQuery(this).attr('class').split(/\b/)[0];
                jQuery('.'+colID).show();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

But when I click on the save button the array is not getting reconstructed. 
How can I clear it and the construct a new array every time the save button is clicked.
I tried using selectedColsArray.length = 0 after declaring the array. but doesn't work

Comment: what makes you think it isnt getting reconstructed?

Comment: when i console selectedColsArray immediately after the button click it shows the array that was previously constructed.

Comment: do you console it before or after var selectedColsArray =[]; ?

Comment: I think what that has been logged is not the true representation of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since `selectedColsArray` is a variable declared in an anonymous function. A new variable will be declared if the function is to be executed the second time. It is not going to be the same variable.

If a new array is logged and it appears to be similar to the previous one, that means same elements have been pushed to the new array, or you are not be seeing a true representation of the array.

Try dumping the array as string before logging it, you may get a different result.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(selectedColsArray));
```